# Pass parameters from controller to Interceptor's after() action in Grails 3.x

Tags: grails

I need to pass a param from controller to Interceptor's after() action. How can I do that?

Comment: create another action that mimics this action then send it to action2 which will hit it's before interceptor and you are in effect hitting the interceptor after - I think you probably mean / require validation rather than interceptor - if issues fail back {displays form or whatever again} and / or  if ok  then go on to next step - validation is for that

Comment: The best solution will depend on what the information is, whether or not it needs to also be accessible in the view and what you want to do with it.

Comment: I want to display that param in view which need to be set to model in after() action in Interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

You have request and response object available in your before closure of interceptor, but the scope of the request/response object is finished at execution of after closure which takes model object as argument.

```
class YourInterceptor {
    boolean before(){
    //code before reaching respective controller
        return true
    }
   //this part is executed before the view is rendered,
    def afterInterceptor = { model ->
        def myParam = model.yourParam;
    }
}

You can set the model object used above in your controller as
public class YourController {
  //your controller logic
[yourParam: paramValue] // this map is the model object which contains `the data for your view, this object is the model object that is used in after closure of interceptor.`
}
```

Comment: The question arose here since I had to pass the client specific parameter from controller to after() method (setting it to model) and finally to view. Here, no session has been initiated since it has to return back from login page itself in case of no access to that particular user. The issue arises in Single Sign On system where user has access to a client but not to another client.